# How are hyphenation patterns written?

Tags: hyphenation

In my miktex folder I checked the `hyph-en-us.tex` file and found letter patterns written like this:

```
\patterns{    
.ach4    
.ad4der    
.af1t    
...
}
```

What do these dots and numbers mean?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The full explanation can be found in Appendix H of the TeXbook. When TeX considers a word for hyphenation, it splits it into “subwords”. The example in the TeXbook uses “hyphenation”. Markers are added at either end, represented by `.`, and subwords are considered:

```
. h y p h e n a t i o n .
.h hy yp ph he en na at ti io on n.
.hy hyp yph phe hen ena nat ati tio ion on.
.hyp [...] ion.
```

and so on, of any possible length. Each subword is compared with the hyphenation patterns for the current language. A pattern consists of sequences of the form

```
<digit><letter><digit>...<letter><digit>
```

where the `<digit>` is omitted if it is 0; so the first pattern in the list for English is equivalent to

```
0.0a0c0h4
```

The comparison, of course, doesn't consider the digits. Subwords that match no pattern are discarded; in the example only

```
0h0y3p0h0 0h0e2n0 0h0e0n0a4 0h0e0n5a0t0 1n0a0 0n2a0t0 1t0i0o0 2i0o0 0o2n0
```

survive. Between each letter in the original word, the *maximum* value in the list above remains (with 0 by default), so the next step results in

```
.0h0y3p0h0e2n5a4t2i0o2n0.
```

The feasible hyphenation points are those where an *odd* digit appears, in this case

```
hy-phen-ation
```

So the first pattern basically prohibits hyphenating words that start with “ach” after the h, the second one avoids breaking between the two d's words that start with “adder”, because of the large even value; on the contrary, the next pattern says that breaking after f a word starting with “aft” is possible, unless some other pattern is found that has an even value between f and t. The pattern `.anti5s` says that words starting with “antis” can be broken after i (no value above 5 appears in `hyphen.tex`). An even value can be used in a longer pattern to countermand an odd value in a shorter pattern and so on.

Break points that fall at a distance from the boundaries less than `\lefthyphenmin` or `\righthyphenmin` (left and right boundary respectively) are discarded. Since for English we have `\lefthyphenmin=2` and `\righthyphenmin=3`, the two found points are kept. Now TeX adds discretionary items and considers them for breaking the paragraph into lines.

What's a “word”? Basically (but this is not the full truth) it is a sequence of letters in the same font that follows a space. Consult the TeXbook or TeX by Topic for more information.

How are the patterns prepared? It depends. For English, the program `patgen` has been used: it loads a list of hyphenated words and spits out a list of patterns. For Italian, grammatical rules have been used, with low even or odd values (so we find `s2c`, `s2p` and so on, or `b1b`, `c1c` and so on); other patterns have been manually added for avoiding bad breaks, for instance `.di2s3cine` that gives the correct hyphenation for “discinesia”.

Comment: Actually, for some languages, the grammatical rules are so regular that they have been generated  automatically by a program.  This is the case for Turkish, there may be others.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer For Italian they have been originally implemented by hand, as the rules are very simple. Then exceptions have been added, for etymological hyphenation of prefixed or compound words.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphenation_algorithm Here I found the algorithm, which turns the patterns to json and hyps the word. I'm using its python veersion.

Comment: Incorrect last sample. The length 4 sample was not actually in the original LaTeX appendix H, but was mistyped by the poster. It should of course read `.hyp [...] ion.`

Comment: @Marius I'll fix, thanks for spotting.

Comment: You're welcome. I also would like to add that your post helped me understand it better to implement it in our products. Thank you.