# Default language in TexLive installation

Tags: languages, texlive-2018

I am installing TexLive 2018 in MacOS and after running `install-tl` on Terminal I chose `scheme-custom` and then started choosing the `installation collections`. The options "Essential programs and files" and "LaTeX fundamental packages" were already selected, but the option "US and UK English" was not. Actually, none of the languages were selected. I thought texlive always installs the "US and UK English" package by default.

What happens if I don't choose any language when installing texlive?
Will I be able to write anything with TeX/LaTeX at all?

Comment: LaTeX does not need any language package to be used, so you can compile any document as long as you don't provide a specific language (i.e., as long as you don't load the `babel` package). If you do want to use the package to specify language options then you can always install it afterwards at any moment with `tlmgr` (in this case the package `babel-english`).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you aren’t installing using MacTeX?

Comment: @Marijn thank you. I understand that one of the benefits of installing of a package like German is the use of letters like the ss symbol and the dots above the letter `a` and `o`. What is the difference between using LaTeX with the `english` package and without it?

Comment: @HerbSchulz MacTeX seems too heavy with 1.5GB+, so I was thinking to do a custom installation. Would you suggest to go with MacTeX instead?

Comment: @evaristegd : there is a smaller BasicTeX install that can be enlarged to suite your needs using TeX Live Utility (or tonged if you prefer).

Comment: @evaristegd the basic language settings of LaTeX are aimed at American English typography and spelling/grammar/hyphenation/date formatting/..., `babel-english` provides American English, British English, Canadian, Australian, New Zealand. Besides this, by providing English, `babel` allows to standardize (or standardise...) the way language selection and switching is performed in the package.

Comment: @Marijn I think you've answered my question to some extent, would you like to post an answer? (I guess I myself can do it as well) Also, now I have some notion of the benefits of using `babel-english`, but I'd also like to see some examples comparing documents with and without that package

Comment: @Marijn I'll go ahead and answer my own question based on what you say, if you don't mind

Comment: @evaristegd sorry for not replying, I'm on holiday :) please go ahead and make an answer - if I think I have anything to add then I can always write another answer next to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic installation of LaTeX contains language definitions for American English, i.e., hyphenation patterns and localizations like date formats and the names of special sections such as Table of Contents or References. These definitions are used as a default, i.e., when no language-related packages are loaded in a document.

If you want (proper) hyphenation and localization for other languages, then the `babel` package can be used, which supports around 200 languages.

In the package repository CTAN, Babel is organized in subpackages for the different languages, such as `babel-french` or `babel-german` (note that these are somewhat unusual packages because they are not loaded with `\usepackage{babel-somelanguage}`, but instead they provide package options for `babel`, e.g., `\usepackage[french]{babel}`).

There is also a subpackage `babel-english`, which might seem strange because LaTeX already contains language definitions for English. However, the package is still useful for two reasons: 1. it provides definitions for varieties of English other than American English, and 2. it standardizes the way languages are handled (i.e., English is no longer a special case).

The MWE below shows some differences for the language varieties `british` and `american`. For these varieties (called *dialects* in Babel) separate hyphenation rules are provided, as a long list of character sequence patterns with hyphenation positions and a very small list of full word exceptions to the patterns. In the example, *obligatory* is in the American exceptions list but not in the British list, while the other words are based on patterns that are different between the two variants. For more information on the patterns, see [How are hyphenation patterns written?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262588/how-are-hyphenation-patterns-written).

Additionally, the definition of `\today` is localized, and some macros are provided for sections and references which are not defined without loading `babel`. These macros are the same for all English dialects (and therefore also the same as the default values) and normally you don't use them directly in your document, but other packages for formatting titles etc. can use these macros for localization.

Code (ignore `parbox`, `minipage`, `vspace` etc, these are just for presentation purposes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,american]{babel}
\begin{document}
\alsoname\ \ccname\ \headtoname\ \enclname\ \partname
\vspace{1em}
\hrule

\def\ex{\parbox[][10cm][t]{1mm}{not obligatory elevator chilling}\today}
\selectlanguage{british}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\ex
\end{minipage}
\selectlanguage{american}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\ex
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]